# Did I mess up my .profile file?

Tags: macos, path

I was trying to update my system path, followed some directions online and accidentally types:

```
touch ~/.profile
```

Did I overwrite my .profile file? Does this mean that I have destroyed all of my PATH information? If so, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no".

The `touch` command does not modify the data in a file at all. Its effects on a file are:

1. If the file does not exist it is created
2. If the file exists if sets its access time metadata to the current time

There are some more options but in this case they are irrelevant, you can see the whole documentation by typing `man touch` in the terminal.

So, no worries, your `.profile` file was not modified.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are on OSX which doesn't have a `~/.profile` file by default. So you probably didn't do any damage.

Just run `echo $PATH` to confirm that it has the usual directories: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`